# Visual studio core error unable to locate Android Studio executable in macos

Tags: android, flutter, visual-studio-code

```
I using flutter doctor -v
```

> [✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
> • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
> • Xcode 12.5.1, Build version 12E507
> • CocoaPods version 1.10.1
>
> [✓] Chrome - develop for the web
> • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome
>
> [✓] Android Studio (version 4.2)
> • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
> • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
> • Dart plugin can be installed from:
>  https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
> • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.8+10-b944.6916264)
>
> [✓] Connected device (3 available)
> • sdk gphone x86 arm (mobile) • emulator-5554 • android-x86    • Android 11 (API 30) (emulator)
> • macOS (desktop)             • macos         • darwin-x64     • macOS 11.4 20F71 darwin-x64
> • Chrome (web)                • chrome        • web-javascript • Google Chrome 88.0.4324.192
>
> • No issues found!

```
flutter config --machine
```

> {   "android-studio-dir": "/Applications/Android Studio.app",
> "enable-macos-desktop": true,   "android-sdk":
> "/Users/macbook/Library/Android/sdk" }

When i select open in android studio -> show error: "Unable to locate Android Studio executable" in macos
Can anyone help me out here? thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try running:

```
flutter config --android-studio-dir "/Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents"
```

That seems to be the format mine is in (and seems to be [what the extension expects](https://github.com/Dart-Code/Dart-Code/blob/9732feed03f954fe82725e011b0846d3f27d3df6/src/extension/commands/open_in_other_editors.ts#L32)) and it's working for me.

Comment: Thanks @Danny Tuppeny I tried it and it worked. i want to like but at least 15 reputation. thank you

Comment: I think you should be able to mark is as the correct answer without an rep. In any case, glad it's sorted! :-)